# The text box and formatting tools are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I use 
ruby '2.4.1'
rails '5.2.1'

Gemfile

`gem 'trix-rails', require: 'trix'`

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require trix
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require trix
```

in rails_admin add partial from field:

```
<%= form.trix_editor :body, required: true, autofocus: true, class: 'trix-toolbar form-control-lg' %>
```

If I change in this code `trix_editor` on `text_area` everything works well. I get no errors, no input fields with `trix_editor`

Updated:
If you just use the usual page, it works. If in rails_admin, then no.

What is my problem? Help me, please!

Comment: Take a look at the developer console of your browser. If there is no problem in the back end of which the rails log would have notified you, I assume that you will find an error there.

Comment: @ulferts There are no errors in the console. The only thing that is strange is that I do not see the trix.css and trix.js in the list of files to be loaded.